# How to format on save on a file with no changes in JetBrains IDE?

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

If I change a file and press <kbd>Ctrl + S</kbd>, PhpStorm formats and saves file normally. However, if there's a file with no changes and I hit <kbd>Ctrl + S</kbd> then the code is not formatted.

How do I format on save even if there's 0 changes in a file?

Comment: *"How do I format on save even if there's 0 changes in a file?"* Call your code formatter manually?.. If it's built-in formatter -- `Code | Reformat Code` or `Code | Reformat File...`

Comment: Yeah like but I wanna attach the format to "Ctrl + S" just like with VSCode.

Comment: If there is NO changes detected in a file then NO SAVE operation performed.... and therefore no "On save" actions are run. How do you expect to run something "on save" when no "save" if performed (no need for it)?

Comment: A possible workaround is to record a Macro where you call Reformat manually and then Save afterwards. Then reassign that `Ctrl+S` shortcut from Save to your Macro. An example just for your needs: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/using-macros-in-the-editor.html#reformat_on_save

Comment: I am used to vscode. VSCode formats file with "Ctrl + S" even if the file wasn't changed. Anyhow, thanks for that macro tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You can reformat a file with <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> on a Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> on Windows.

Documentation: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/reformat-and-rearrange-code.html